How to update table in oracle with a join on 2 tables
In this my question
My db has a table street that includes a district name. This table is joined with another table 'district', which also contains district names
If name match, I want to update the district_id in the table street table with corresponding id from the table district
Here my query:
select st.districts, (select min(id) from tbl_dm_district dis where Initcap(dis.name) = Initcap(st.districts)) as new_districts_id
from tbl_dm_street st
where EXISTS ( select 1 from tbl_dm_district dis where Initcap(dis.name) = Initcap(st.districts) );

My update table:
UPDATE tbl_dm_street st
SET district_id = (
    SELECT min(id)
    FROM tbl_dm_district dis
    WHERE Initcap(dis.name) = Initcap(st.districts)
)
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tbl_dm_district dis
    WHERE Initcap(dis.name) = Initcap(st.districts)
);

I have checked query that seems to work fine, but still I would appreciate it if others could review it. Thanks.

Query you wrote is OK.
As an alternative, see merge statement, compare how they behave and use the one that works better.
merge into tbl_dm_street st
  using (select initcap(dis.name) district_name,
                min(dis.id) district_id
         from tbl_dm_district dis
         group by initcap(dis.name)
        ) d
  on (initcap(st.districts) = d.district_name)
  when matched then update set
    st.district_id = d.district_id;


Is correct:`merge into tbl_dm_street st 
using (
    select initcap(dis.name) as districts_name, min(dis.id) as districts_id 
    from tbl_dm_district dis group by Initcap(dis.name) 
    ) d
on (initcap(st.districts) = d.districts_name) 
when matched then 
update set st.districts_id = d.districts_id; `
Sorry, I forgot to include the GROUP BY clause. I'm glad you found it yourself and fixed it.
